# UICollectionView fast scrolling displays wrong images in the cell when new items are appended asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView which displays images in a grid but as I scroll rapidly it displays the wrong image in the cell momentarily until the image is downloaded from the S3 storage and then the correct image is displayed.

I have seen questions and answers relating to this problem on SO before but none of the solutions are working for me. The dictionary `let items = [[String: Any]]()` is filled after an API call. I need the cell to discard the image from the recycled cell. Right now there is an unpleasant image "dancing" effect.

Here is my code:

```
var searchResults = [[String: Any]]()

let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    let item = searchResults[indexPath.item]

    cell.backgroundColor = .white

    cell.itemLabel.text = item["title"] as? String

    let imageUrl = item["img_url"] as! String

    let url = URL(string: imageUrl)

    let request = Request(url: url!)

    cell.itemImageView.image = nil

    Nuke.loadImage(with: request, into: cell.itemImageView)

    return cell
}


class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var itemImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.backgroundColor = .white
    return imageView
}()


 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

 ---------

 }

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    itemImageView.image = nil
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}    
}
```

I changed my cell image loading to the following code:

```
cell.itemImageView.image = nil

APIManager.sharedInstance.myImageQuery(url: imageUrl) { (image) in

guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell
                else { return }

cell.itemImageView.image = image

cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Here is my API manager.

```
struct APIManager {

static let sharedInstance = APIManager()

func myImageQuery(url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {

    if let url = URL(string: url) {

        Manager.shared.loadImage(with: url, token: nil) { // internal to Nuke

            guard let image = $0.value as UIImage? else {
                return completionHandler(nil)
            }

            completionHandler(image)
        }
    }
}
```

If the user scrolls past the content limit my collection view will load more items. This seems to be the root of the problem where cell reuse is reusing images. Other fields in the cell such as item title are also swapped as new items are loaded.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + view.frame.size.height) > (scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.8) {

        loadItems()
    }
}
```

Here is my data loading function

```
func loadItems() {

    if loadingMoreItems {
        return
    }

    if noMoreData {
        return
    }

    if(!Utility.isConnectedToNetwork()){

        return
    }

    loadingMoreItems = true

    currentPage = currentPage + 1

    LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(view: self.view)

    APIManager.sharedInstance.getItems(itemURL, page: currentPage) { (result, error) -> () in

        if error != nil {

        }

        else {

            self.parseData(jsonData: result!)
        }

        self.loadingMoreItems = false

        LoadingOverlay.shared.hideOverlayView()
    }
}


func parseData(jsonData: [String: Any]) {

    guard let items = jsonData["items"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return
    }

    if items.count == 0 {

        noMoreData = true

        return
    }

    for item in items {

        searchResults.append(item)
    }

    for index in 0..<self.searchResults.count {

        let url = URL(string: self.searchResults[index]["img_url"] as! String)

        let request = Request(url: url!)

        self.preHeatedImages.append(request)

    }

    self.preheater.startPreheating(with: self.preHeatedImages)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

//        appendCollectionView(numberOfItems: items.count)

        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `SDImage` library

Comment: If the labels that are being set synchronously are also being messed up that is a much bigger issuer than the images being set incorrectly.  Could you share related to `loadItems`.  When you get more items do you reload the tableview, or insert rows?

Comment: The labels look OK. I am reloading the collectionView. I have edited the question to include data loading. The preheating is for Nuke to preload images but the preheat array is not directly accessed, it's just for caching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the collection view scrolls a cell out of bounds, the collection view may reuse the cell to display a different item. This is why you get cells from a method named `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)`.

You need to make sure, when the image is ready, that the image view is still supposed to display that item's image.

I recommend you change your `Nuke.loadImage(with:into:)` method to take a closure instead of an image view:

```
struct Nuke {

    static func loadImage(with request: URLRequest, body: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

That way, in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`, you can load the image like this:

```
Nuke.loadImage(with: request) { [weak collectionView] (image) in
    guard let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell
    else { return }
    cell.itemImageView.image = image
}
```

If the collection view is no longer displaying the item in any cell, the image will be discarded. If the collection view is displaying the item in any cell (even in a different cell), you'll store the image in the correct image view.

Comment: Can I have some code using Nuke for the struct please? I tried using the Nuke Manager but getting error `Ambiguous reference to member loadimage`.

Comment: I don't know anything about `Nuke` or `Nuke.loadImage(with:into:)`. I assume it's something you wrote, because you use it in the code in your question. I have no idea what it actually does to load the image.

Comment: Agreed. And, for the sake of future readers, if it's possible that cells might be inserted, you can't even rely on `indexPath`, but rather have to go back to the model and confirm what the right index path is, see if that cell is visible (as rob has shown above), and use that.

Comment: I haven't used a model other than the dictionary as shown. I have no idea how to accomplish what you are suggesting. Items are appended in 30 item batches as the user scrolls. This seems to be the real problem here.

Comment: The guard statement did not work for me. I have a structure similar to what was suggested in this answer to load the image in an escaping closure using the Nuke Manager.

Comment: "If the collection view is no longer displaying the item in any cell, the image will be discarded." - It might be helpful to instead **cache** the image locally, for future display once the user scrolls back. Bandwidth isn't free or infinite ;)

Comment: ...but that's outside the scope of the current question, I guess.

Comment: The images are cached by Nuke. The issue is reused cells not setting image to nil.

Comment: In this code example, do I still use `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell` ? If so, it didn't work. If not, how do I return the cell?

Comment: It still swaps cells. I got some success using performBatchUpdates instead of dataReload() but I just saw a once off crash due to reuse of a freed cell. Not sure of the exact message, I'll do some testing tomorrow and try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Whenever the cell is reused, its `prepareForReuse` method is called. You can reset your cell here. In your case, you can set a default image in the image view here till the original image is downloaded.

```
 override func prepareForReuse()
    {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultImage"
    }
```

Comment: I tried to set the image to nil in that function but it didn't work. I didn't want to use a default image. This suggestion doesn't work either.

Comment: Try this: self.imageView.image = nil

Answer (score 2):

```
@discardableResult
public func loadImage(with url: URL,
                  options: ImageLoadingOptions = ImageLoadingOptions.shared,
                  into view: ImageDisplayingView,
                  progress: ImageTask.ProgressHandler? = nil,
                  completion: ImageTask.Completion? = nil) -> ImageTask? {
return loadImage(with: ImageRequest(url: url), options: options, into: view, progress: progress, completion: completion)
}
```

all Nuke API's return an ImageTask when requesting unless the image was in the cache. Hold reference to this ImageTask if there is one.  In the prepareForReuse function. call ImageTask.cancel() in it and set the imageTask to nil.

Answer (score 0):

From the Nuke project page:

> Nuke.loadImage(with:into:) method cancels previous outstanding request associated with the target. Nuke holds a weak reference to a target, when the target is deallocated the associated request gets cancelled automatically.

And as far as I can tell you are using their example code correctly:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    cell.imageView.image = nil
    Nuke.loadImage(with: url, into: cell.imageView)
    ...
}
```

You are explicitly setting the UIImageViews image to nil so there should actually be no way it could display an image until Nuke loads a new image into the target.

Also Nuke will cancel a previous request. I'm using Nuke myself and don't have these issues. Are you sure your "changed code" isn't the faulty piece here? For me everything seems to be correct and I don't see an issue why it shouldn't work.

One possible issue could be the reload of the whole collection view though. We should always try to provide the best user experience so if you alter the datasource of the collection view, try to use performBatchUpdates to animate the inserts/updates/moves/deletes.

A nice library which automatically can take care of this is Dwifft for example.

Comment: I tried using a nib but it didn't work either with the same code as you used, there was still cell swapping. It only happens when i append records to the model dictionary.

Comment: Well for this problem I cold recommend you the Dwifft library. It would allow you to get the items, append them to the existing items and then set them as the items of your datasource. Dwifft automatically does a diff compare and then updates your collectionview animated. Besides that, probably reloading the whole collectionview is the problem. Try to properly implement performBatchUpdates. If you get an error, you are doing something wrong ;)

Comment: @xxlesaxx, write performBatchUpdates up as an answer for the points. It doesn't completely fix the cell swapping problem but it works a lot better than dataReload()

Comment: While performBatchUpdates works better it still swaps cells around a bit on fast scroll back upwards. Also the effect of having 2 ietsm side by side in a stack view produces a weird visual effect. I'd prefer to use dataReload() if I found a solution.

Comment: Hmm without knowing all the side effects other code might have its hard to tell where the problem is. In such cases, I always like to start a fresh project with a single view controller which does only the one thing which does not work (in your case showing a grid of images). From my experience, UIStackView inside UICollectionViewCell with UIImage and other Views work well in conjunction with Nuke. Of course one has to reset the image properly (I like to use prepareForReuse rather then cellForItemAt).

Comment: Could you setup such a little demo project and put it on github?

Comment: It's not so easy to create a demo as the URL's are live and I'd like to limit some of the proprietary code. I did nil the image in prepareForResuse which did not work but have read that the function should not be used for content. Meantime, I did use performBatchUpdates instead of reloadData() which mostly fixed the issues although there is still some cell flicker. I need to allocate these points fast so please write that up since you mentioned it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your last sentence. Sorry. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: This question has a bounty of 50 points which must be awarded to an answer within 2 hours from now. Your comment about performBatchUpdates  was closest to a solution but is not an answer. Try to write it up as a proper answer to the question.